# Запуск Docker. Ошибка при запуске Hardware assisted virtualization

Tags: windows, docker, devops

Ошибка при запуске.

Нашел решение в интернете в три способа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Enable Hyper V - You can do this by running the following command as administrator. - dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All

2 .Enable Hypervisor with following command - bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto.

You should run either one of the above commands. And you need to restart the system to apply the changes.

If the problem persist probably Hyper-V on your system is corrupted, so

3. Open in Control Panel > [Programs] > [Windows Features] and completely uncheck all Hyper-V related components. Restart the system. Enable Hyper-V again. Restart.

По сути это все решения которые есть в интернете, попадаются одни и теже. Но не один не решает проблему. Хоть перезагружай комп, или нет, результат один и тот же. Сегодня ради докера обновился до Windows Pro, до этого стояла Home. Ключ покупал в интернете, обновлялся через виндоус через официальный источник. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А в БИОСе вы включили виртуализацию?

Comment: нет @АлексейБобрович

Comment: В ошибке четко сказано что вам нужно включить виртуализацию в Биосе вашего ПК, у каждой материнки это делается по своему. Docker - это своеобразная маленькая виртуальная машина и для ее работы как и для работы любой виртуальной машины нужно включить виртуализацию.

Comment: @АлексейБобрович Спасибо, я как-то все внимание уделил этим трем способам а самое главное упустил. Я включил в биосе и все заработало. Можете дать ответ, отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ошибке четко сказано что вам нужно включить виртуализацию в Биосе вашего ПК, у каждой материнки это делается по своему. Docker - это своеобразная маленькая виртуальная машина и для ее работы как и для работы любой виртуальной машины нужно включить виртуализацию.